# physical path for application documents directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

what is the physical path of any application's document directory ? (on Mac OS X Lion)
I know that there is UUID for each app on that folder but could not find it on my system until now

Comment: NSLog(@"Documents: %@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]);

Comment: @VladimirGrigorov you should add your comment as an Answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open

> /Users/UserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3.2/Applications

Assuming 4.3.2 is the sdk version being used. Note that there's a Library folder inside MacintoshHD too, but you have to goto the one inside the current user's home directory. Also in Lion the user's Library folder is hidden by default. You'd need to click on Go on menu bar, holding the option key, to see it.

Comment: I have 5 MacMini here, all with Lion / Xcode 4.2 and there is not "iPhone Simulator" folder in /Users/System Name/Library/Application Support. I tried to find out this folder with the Search tool but no luck. No "iPhone Simulator" anywhere. Is there a chance this folder name has changed ?

Comment: Hidden folder in OSX means, it wouldn't be visible from spotlight search as well. Try the Go menu bar button, as I mentioned in my answer. To permanently unhide Library folder, execute: "chflags nohidden ~/Library/" in your terminal, without quotes.

Answer (score 4):

In Ios 5 this path has change it is as below
find this from GO menu of finder and find with Goto Folder and past this link

```
  /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
```

Comment: i am not finding iphone simulator folder.

Answer (score 1):

/Users/System Name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3(target)/Applications

here you will see a bunch of folders for each application.Better rearrange them by date.Find yar application's folder inside that.And you will get your application document directory there.

Comment: what you mean by System Name ? 'coz I did not find Library folder inside my user name folder

Comment: i opened /Library/Application Support folder but there is no iPhone Simulator folder inside it, where to find it please ?