# Library folder in MAC OS 10.7.4 missing

Tags: iphone, macos, osx-lion

Am using Mac OS version 10.7.4. In my iPhone application am creating a database. Now i want to check that database in documents directory path. And i know it'll be stored in users/iphone/library section. But in mac os 10.7.4 version Library Folder is missing in finder. Where can i find the library folder in my mac machine? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307265/physical-path-for-application-documents-directory/8309356#8309356

Comment: Nothing changes.If you see the answers in the thread, you'd come to know that Library folder in 10.7 is hidden by default and how to temporarily or permanently make it visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mac-Lion, Library files are hidden by default. To make it visible, open the terminal and type the following code

chflags nohidden ~/Library

Now relaunch the finder, you can see the library files.

Comment: 1. you don't need to relaunch, 2. we don't need duplicate answers.

Comment: Actually I posted my answer before I see your answer. But since my internet connection is low at this moment, my comment was posted after you. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

its located at this path **~/Library**

Comment: I know it stored in library path. But i am unable to see the library folder in finder in MAC Os version 10.7.4.

Comment: Its because its hidden, try using terminal to access it or right click on **Finder** than select **Go to Folder**

Comment: In mac os 10.7.4 version that library folder is missing boss.

Comment: Where could it possibly go :) check this [link](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/unhide-library-folder-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion.428277/)

Comment: One easy solution.. when you create your database print its path using NSLog and use Finder to locate it

Answer (score 0):

Type this in your Terminal and it's going to be revealed immediately:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library/
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself.

To unhide the library folder,

1. Go to Terminal and type "chflags nohidden ~/Library/". You'll find the Library folder in your finder now.

To hide your Library folder again,

1. Go to Terminal and type "chflags hidden ~/Library". This will hide your library folder from finder.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *document = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(document);
```

open your finder, GO > Go to folder  > paste the path

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following solutions: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/access-hidden-user-library-files.html

Apple made the user library folder hidden by default with the 10.7 release. If it's necessary to access these files for Adobe-related troubleshooting, use one of the following methods to make the user library content visible.

**Method 1**

In the Finder, choose Go > Go To Folder.
In the Go To Folder dialog, type ~/Library
Click Go.

**Method 2**

Hold down the Alt (Option) key when using the Go menu. The user library folder is listed below the current user's home directory.

Note: After you open the Library folder, you can drag the Library icon from the top of that window to the Dock, Side Bar, or toolbar. That way, it's readily accessible.

**Method 3**

The following method makes the user library folder permanently visible.

Note: Adobe recommends that only advanced users use this method.

Launch Terminal from Mac HD > Applications > Utilities.
From within Terminal type the following command and press Return:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

Enter the system administrator password, if prompted, and press Return.

Note: The System administrator password is not visible as you type it.

Close Terminal for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Got to Utilities and open Terminal and simply execute this query to show Library Folder

chflags nohidden ~/Library/

and for hiding any Folder use same query with "hidden" word like

chflags hidden ~/Library

Answer (score 0):

I tried chflags command but not work for me(10.13.4). It was solved with steps:

1. open /Users/${username} in finder
2. right click and popup shows, click "show view options", and a new popup shows
3. check "Show Library Folder"