# iPhone simulator - where is the doc directory?

Tags: ios, plist

Is this it?

ApplicationSupport/iPhoneSimulator/6.0/Applications/.../Documents or is it within the package contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307265/physical-path-for-application-documents-directory).  It is stored in the Users folder and then down some under the SDK version identifier.

Answer (score 1):

In your home directory, goto the library folder (in lion and mountain lion the library folder is hidden). You can find it by clicking Go> Goto Folder, then type in library, then application support, iPhone sim... etc etc. example below

/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications

Comment: Yeah, I was there, just wasn't sure if it was the Documents folder within the App folder or within the package within the app folder. I got it though, just logged it in my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Users/User/Library folder is hidden by default. You'll first need to [unhide hidden files in mac using terminal](http://beageek.biz/how-to-access-xcode-simulator-directory/), then you can access the iphone simulator doc directory at the following url -

> /Users/YOURUSER/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/IOSVERSION/Applications/APPID/Documents/file.txt